# PHP ZipArchive - zip corrupt

Tags: php, apache

On archiving  more number of files , zip is returning a empty zip file which cannot be open and its corrupted.

When i try to pint Zip archive object , i got this:

> ZipArchive Object
>   (
>       [status] => 5
>       [statusSys] => 2
>       [numFiles] => 84
>       [filename] => /root/zip/3810.zip
>       [comment] =>
>   )

The file is not even created.

for lesss number files it working fine .

> ZipArchive Object ( [status] => 0 [statusSys] => 0 [numFiles] => 0 [filename] => [comment] => )

What is this status and statusSys?

How can i debug?

Comment: $zip = new ZipArchive();
for(){

Comment: filename is a combination of datetime

Comment: @zod Edit your question to include the code; don't add it as comments.

Comment: How can i know who down vote me ??? :(

Comment: @zod People will frequently leave info about why they down-voted you. If you clean the question up you might earn an up-vote to balance things out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure after you've zipped everything that you `ZipArchive::close()` after you've added all of your files. If you don't use the `close()` function then the zip file is never created.

This would be done with:

```
$zip->close();
```

Comment: If you have some debug echos or print_r stuff in the function, these will corrupt the output zip archive and you will create a corrupted file.